# Using jQuery (window).resize but element dissapears

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a submenu that is scrolls with the site using position:fixed; I am using jQuery to calculate where it should sit as it's outside of the main content of the site.
It's working fine except for when I resize the browser window; it then disappears from view. Looking at the code in dev tools, it's still there and should be visible.

Perhaps there is something wrong with my script? Your help would be very much appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // Sub Menu Placement
  calculation();
  jQuery(window).resize(calculation);

  function calculation() {
      var location = jQuery(".page-content-section .page-content-section-inner").offset();
            var locationTop = jQuery(".header").offset();

      var left = location.left;
      left = left - 0;

      var top = locationTop.top;
      top = top + jQuery('.header').height();

      jQuery("#submenu").css({
        //'position': 'absolute',
        'position' : 'fixed',
        'top': top + 'px',
        'left': left + 'px'
      });
  } 

});
```

Comment: None of the logic in the `calculation()` function relies on the dimensions of the window - hence changing the window size makes no difference to the location. It would really help diagnose the problem if you could provide a working example in a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: If the page resizes, then the header height can increase/decrease and also the location of the page-content-section will move close/further to the browser window. So wouldn't that mean that calculation() is relavent here?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing it working - or even your HTML and CSS

Comment: I have a working link http://website-test-lab.com/sites/linearmotion/contact/ and will try and get a JSFiddle setup asap

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue:

I changed this line:

```
top = top + jQuery('.header').height();
```

to this:

```
top = jQuery('.header').height();
```